# Twitter follower count

Tags: api, twitter

If someone could help me with this. It suddenly stopped working and i have no idea why.

```
<if test="$this->settings['showTwitter']=='yes'">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json',
   data: {screen_name: 'kwcommunity'},
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {
       $('#followers').html(data.followers_count);
   }
});
});
</script>

 <a href="{$this->settings['twitterURL']}" title="Follow us on Twitter" class='twitterButton' target='_blank'>Twitter: <span id="followers"></span></a>
</if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using API 1 witch is [deprecated](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#Deprecation_of_v1.0_of_the_API). Migrate your code to API 1.1 to get this working again.